# Return redirect to login page in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

In laravel 5.3 i want when i press back button of browser, it always redirect to login page and flush session. Its doesn't go to the back page. something like

```
if(Redirect->back()){
  session()->flush('email');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is a great ideea to put redirect back function into a if statement. see \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector. The common use for back function is to redirect back to a form when the validation has failed. hope this will help.